# How can I force new browser windows to open on my main display?

Tags: macos, display, window-manager

I use a MacBook Air at work connected to a larger display, which while working is my main display. I use the MacBook's display as a secondary screen on which I usually have a browser open with some tools. If I cmd-tab to the browser from another application and create a new window with cmd-n it always opens on my secondary display, since I already have one window open there. What I want is for new windows to always open on the main display. Is this possible?

Comment: I've "solved" this by installing Chrome Canary and using that as the browser on my secondary display…but the question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your browser in fullscreen mode? (Using the 2 diagonal arrows button in the upper right corner of the window)

I have a very similar setup and it works exactly as you are asking.

- MacBook Pro connected to a Thunderbolt Display
- Thunderbolt Display is the primary (with the Dock), MBP is secondary
- Chrome running on the MBP screen in fullscreen mode
- ⌘+Tab to Chrome, which activates the app on the MBP screen
- ⌘+N to create new Chrome window, which appears on the primary Thunderbolt display

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Chrome icon on your Dock, select "Options", and check that you didn't have Chrome assigned to a specific monitor. You can select "None" or specify your main monitor, as you prefer.